# Bootstrap 3 Button Groups

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

**Bootstrap 3

I'm trying to make each set of button group unique but the different groups are interfering with each other

```html
<label>Payment Mode</label>
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Cash / Cheque / Bank Transfer </button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">JobsBuddy Disbursement</button>
</div>

<label>Payment Period</label>
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Immediate</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"> More Than 1 day</button>
</div>
```

How do i keep it unique in it's own group

Comment: Define ``interfering with each other``

Comment: Means when i click the button on payment mode,then click a button on payment period, the payment mode gets unselected

Comment: use name field? A radio in HTML unselect anything having same 'name'.

Answer (score 18):

You may want to use the Bootstrap provided **radio button** groups (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons), and then use the `reset` method to clear the other group..

**HTML:**

```
<label>Payment Mode</label>
  <div id="mode-group" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
      <input type="radio" name="mode" id="option1"> Cash / Cheque / Bank Transfer
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
      <input type="radio" name="mode" id="option2"> JobsBuddy Disbursement
    </label>
  </div>

  <label>Payment Period</label>
  <div id="period-group" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
      <input type="radio" name="period" id="period1"> Immediate
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
      <input type="radio" name="period" id="period2"> More Than 1 day
    </label>
  </div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
// unselect period when mode is selected
$("#mode-group .btn").on('click',function(){

  $("#period-group").button('reset');

});
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/86422

Comment: thanks , actually I dont need it to reset , just need each group to be unique,  I will edit accordingly and test it out thanks !

Comment: This doesn't work to me, i'm quite astonished that it works for you on the demo link, because i've tried everything and still one button-group conflicts with another button-group. This happens also in bootstrap doc page. i've tried to add ids in btn-groups but no succeed :-(

Comment: This doesn't answer the user's question. The same problem happens in this example: if you check one button in your Payment Period group, clicking on a button on the Payment Mode will uncheck it, and viceversa, plus the user is not willing to use a different kind of button.

Answer (score 4):

Click the button in the btn-group doesn't set a (active) class. The button gets a different background-color cause it is focussed (:focus). Clicking a button in a different btn-group sets the focus to this button.

Use something like this to set an active class per btn-group:

```
$('.btn-group button').click(function()
{
    $(this).parent().children().removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AngularJS the [Angular UI bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/buttons) has a great solution.

Basically do the following using the btnRadio directive.

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="radioModel" btn-radio="'Left'">Left</label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="radioModel" btn-radio="'Middle'">Middle</label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="radioModel" btn-radio="'Right'">Right</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

To keep unique button just don't use **class="btn-group"**:

```
<label>Payment Mode</label>
 <div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Cash / Cheque / Bank Transfer </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">JobsBuddy Disbursement</button>
 </div>

 <label>Payment Period</label>
 <div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Immediate</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"> More Than 1 day</button>
 </div>
```

This class is used for series of buttons. Check documentation of [Buttons Group](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups)

Comment: i cant seem to find any more of those class http://paste.laravel.com/XkQ my full source. Thanks in advance :x

Comment: infact the groups in the documentation conflicts each other

Comment: This is totally false. Removing the `btn-group` class doesn't solve the problem (all buttons, independently of their group, interfere with each other, that is, every button acts as belonging to the same group), plus breaks the style of the buttons. Please don't make up unuseful "answers".

Answer (score -1):

Just to simplify it for the next person to come looking, here's the solution code from the Bootstrap website:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary active">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked> Radio 1 (preselected)
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Radio 2
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> Radio 3
  </label>
</div>
```

Basically, you style the labels as buttons and code the options as regular radio buttons to separate one set of options from the other.

Comment: User is not using radio buttons. This makes this answer totally unuseful. For instance, it's invalid if you are trying to use justified button groups.

Comment: How would one set up a form group that has mutually exclusive options? I thought that was the point of radio buttons--you can only choose one of them.

Comment: Yeah, that's the point of radio buttons. But the user is NOT using radio buttons. You could also accomplish the same result with an option list, but I doubt it would barely be useful for this user.

Comment: Oh. My assumption was that even if he wasn't using radio buttons currently, that was going to be the way to get the functionality he was after. I'm going to leave my response in any case, because I still think that's a reasonable assumption.